# Markdown-supporting note taking app with cloud sync between macOS and iOS

Tags: ios, note-taking, macos, markdown

I am seeking a note-taking app that must have the following features:

- Runs on macOS
- Notes are written in Markdown
- Notes can be tagged
- Notes are synced to either a server managed by the app's company (so no eating up my Dropbox space) **or** notes are synced to a self-hosted, free (as in beer, and preferrably speech) server process that I can run on Ubuntu
- Either there is an iOS app or else a web interface that is usable on iOS (Boostnote fails this hard)
- Mass import & export of notes is possible

Features that are not required but would be nice to have:

- GitHub-flavored Markdown
- Either a command-line client or an API so I can write my own
- Notable notes, tags, & searches can be bookmarked
- Free as in beer